# Bevel. Blender vs Maya

Tags: bevel

just made some tests on how bevel works on non planar surfaces in blender and maya. I can't seem to find out how to make the same result as in maya, i tried all the width types, transforms are applied. Any ideas on what am i doing wrong and how to avoid this jiggled results in blender?
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Are you looking to make the flow more seamless? It's possible the bevel modifier might just not be 'polished' enough yet. It shouldn't cause any issues though, since it's on flat areas.

Comment: You might have to use something like Loop Tools to smooth it out. It is an addon which can be activated in User Preferences.